# PathAuto and Purl not working together

Tags: path-aliases

I'm currently using [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) in my project to automatically create aliases for nodes which I'm sure many of you do. But my problems lies with [Purl](https://www.drupal.org/project/purl) (Persistent url) which is supposed to add a prefix to my url.

For example `/blog/some-blog` should become `/kiosk/<id>/blog/some-blog`. The purl provider does this without any issue (I use Path pair) meaning if I go to `/kiosk/<id>/blog/some-blog` it will show me the correct page, my issue here is that links within the `/kiosk/<id>/` context should be rewritten to contain `/kiosk/<id>/` to make sure I stay in the same context.

This works, as long the link has not been rewritten by an url-alias.

**For example:** I have a link inside the blog which refers to another blog post, let's say `node/15`. If `node/15` does not have an alias the link would simply be `/kiosk/<id>/node/15`. BUT if `node/15` has an alias, let's say `my-other-blog-post`, the link does not contain the prefix.

The link should be `/kiosk/<id>/my-other-blog-post` but instead becomes `/my-other-blog-post` .

So my question is, how do I force url-alias to accept the path prefix without removing it?

Comment: You know that purl is beta? I think it might actually be a bug, and you have better chance of finding help in issue queue than here.